# jQuery Isotope's first filter is not animating

Tags: jquery-isotope, jquery-masonry

I'm using Isotope filtering with Masonry on this site:

http://ihavepinkhair.com/wp/blog/

The filter works fine and it animates after the first filter just fine, but I'm a details person and I can't get over the fact that the first filter doesn't animate properly.

My app.js looks like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

// init Masonry
var $gridMason = $('.grid-mason').masonry({
  // options
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
  percentPosition: true,
  transitionDuration: '0.8s'
});

// layout Masonry after each image loads
$gridMason.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
  $gridMason.masonry('layout');
});

// filtering
$('.filter-button-group').on( 'click', 'a', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
  $gridMason.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
});

});
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks, Jared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Masonry and Isotope are separate scripts and not used together. Isotope has a "masonry" layout which is not masonry.js and it can filter and sort while masonry.js can not filter or sort. Your initializing your items first with masonry.js and then trying to filter with isotope.js which loads only after you click the first filter button. Get rid of masonry.js and use isotope.js only.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

// init Masonry
var $gridMason = $('.grid-mason').isotope({
// options
itemSelector: '.grid-item',
masonry: {
columnWidth: '.grid-sizer'
},
percentPosition: true,
transitionDuration: '0.8s'
});

// layout Masonry after each image loads
$gridMason.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
$gridMason.isotope('layout');
});

// filtering
$('.filter-button-group').on( 'click', 'a', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
$gridMason.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
});

});
```